# How run telnet process in background in linux

Tags: linux, shell, unix, solaris

```
telnet IP>>new.txt & disown
```

This command gives job ID but all the log's of telnet session is not written to output file only connection status is written as:

```
Trying I.P...
Connected to I.P.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

Same with using nohup:

```
nohup telnet IP>>new.txt & disown
```

I need to log all the output from the telnet session to file till connection is closed in background

Comment: how are you sending commands into telnet?

Comment: Its a console access to sever, so I need to monitor log when it restarts. I don't need to give any input to telnet session when server restarts it starts logging itself to telnet session

Comment: do you see output from the server when it restarts if you don't background the telnet?

Comment: Yes, it shows output